# Change initialize method in subclass of an R6 class

Tags: r, r6

Let's say I have a R6 class `Person`:

```
library(R6)

Person <- R6Class("Person",
  public = list(name = NA, hair = NA,
                initialize = function(name, hair) {
                  self$name <- name
                  self$hair <- hair
                  self$greet()
                },
                greet = function() {
                  cat("Hello, my name is ", self$name, ".\n", sep = "")
                })
)
```

If I want to create a subclass whose `initialize` method should be the same except for adding one more variable to `self` how would I do this?
I tried the following:

```
PersonWithSurname <- R6Class("PersonWithSurname",
  inherit = Person,
  public = list(surname = NA,
                initialize = function(name, surname, hair) {
                  Person$new(name, hair)
                  self$surname <- surname
                })
)
```

However when I create a new instance of class `PersonWithSurname` the fields `name` and `hair` are `NA`, i.e. the default value of class `Person`.

```
PersonWithSurname$new("John", "Doe", "brown")
Hello, my name is John.
<PersonWithSurname>
   Inherits from: <Person>
   Public:
     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
     greet: function () 
     hair: NA
     initialize: function (name, surname, hair) 
     name: NA
     surname: Doe
```

In `Python` I would do the following:

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, name, hair):
    self.name = name
    self.hair = hair
    self.greet()

  def greet(self):
    print "Hello, my name is " + self.name

class PersonWithSurname(Person):
  def __init__(self, name, surname, hair):
    Person.__init__(self, name, hair)
    self.surname = surname
```

Comment: Actually in Python you should use `super()`, not the parent class’ name. This prevents mistakes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

R6 works very much like Python in this regard; that is, you just call `initialize` on the `super` object:

```
PersonWithSurname <- R6Class("PersonWithSurname",
  inherit = Person,
  public = list(surname = NA,
                initialize = function(name, surname, hair) {
                  super$initialize(name, hair)
                  self$surname <- surname
                })
)
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find anything about `super` in the vignettes.

Comment: @Tommy Indeed, the documentation is a bit lacking in this regard, but the [Introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html) mentions `super` at least, though it doesn’t specifically explain superclass initialisation. The behaviour can be guessed from the (nontrivial) implementation of R6. Furthermore, the projects contains [test cases](https://github.com/wch/R6/blob/f6cb021a5da2581aebda1d49afd872cd80967479/tests/testthat/test-nonportable-inheritance.R#L35) which show this behaviour.

Comment: The updated link to the [Introduction vignette](https://r6.r-lib.org/articles/Introduction.html).